# How to capture X-CSRF-TOKEN using Jmeter from HTTP Header Manager

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded login scenario of a page (built on Java and Angular) and the very first request doesn't show X-CSRF-TOKEN in the Response Data tab, but the second HTTP request has X-CSRF-TOKEN in the HTTP Header Manager, and when I try to run the script the 2nd HTTP Request shows the response code 401 as the recorded X-CSRF-TOKEN is no longer valid, so I was wondering how to write a regular expression to capture the X-CSRF-TOKEN by creating reg expression as a post processor.

Please let know how to capture the X-CSRF-TOKEN dynamically.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looking into [Angular’s XSRF: How It Works](https://stormpath.com/blog/angular-xsrf) article:

> - Look for a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` on the current domain.
> - If that cookie is found, it reads the value and adds it to the request as the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header.

So you will not be able to locate `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in the response data, instead you should be looking for `XSRF-TOKEN` [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) in the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to send the following header:

   - Name: `X-XSRF-TOKEN`
   - Value: `${COOKIE_XSRF-TOKEN}`

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check embedded resource of 1st requests-response from JMeter or browser? If you don't see it there then can you check with the developer? sometimes tokens generated at client/browser side (like using javascript) and this activity won't get captured in Jmeter.